# Multiple GridComponent in Kendo UI for Angular

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-ui-angular2

I have multiple grid's on one View and I want to use GridComponent [link](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/api/GridComponent/#toc-selector) on one page but this GridComponent works only for first grid. Second (and others) grid don't work.

edit: respone from telerik support: [link](https://www.telerik.com/account/support-tickets/view-ticket?threadid=1136714)

```
To select all components of a certain type on the page, using such an approach, you will need to use ViewChildren instead of ViewChild, and loop through the resulting collection of components to process each of them as necessary, e.g.:

http://plnkr.co/edit/p78lNUe6vUvF2AabSUIX?p=preview

Alternatively you can use template reference variables to access each component individually by its unique tag instead, e.g.:
http://plnkr.co/edit/9xRPBIinsyLg3XNK4jsz?p=preview
```

Comment: if its like kendo grid, just use different id's and templates. I use multiple kendo grids on one page and can achieve it

Comment: Different templates you mean different html View? Is it possible to have two fully functional kendo-grids one one html view?

Comment: Yes, just copy the grid and change out the id, so one is #grid and another is #gridTwo